# vb NET - how get text form Word bullet point?

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I can get the text from the all tag (by range), but how get text from each bullet point ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wbXo.png

Comment: Show use what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate through ListParagraphs not standard Paragraphs.

```
For i = 1 To doc.Content.ListParagraphs.Count
    Set rng = doc.Content.ListParagraphs(1).Range.Text
    'do something
Next
```